# CSV color data not rendering

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, colors

I'm trying to color the circles per a .csv data, column "COLOR". The "COLOR" includes "red", "yellow" , "green" *-but right now the colors are not transferring... just the default black...*

```
var col = function(d) {return d.COLOR};

svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 15)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", col)
      .style("opacity", ".5")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", .9);
          tooltip.html(d["Cereal Name"] + "<br/> (" + xValue(d)
            + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

 data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.POPULATION = +d.POPULATION;
    d.REVENUE = +d.REVENUE;
    d.COLOR = +d.COLOR;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: I dont see any issues in this...one possibility could be that `d.COLOR` is not present in the data.

Comment: @cyril : I added a bit more detail showing the respective csv file along with the code which pulls the COLOR data from the file. am I missing something here? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `COLOR` values in your CSV contain quotation marks `"` which will be part of the parsed strings in `data`. Therefore, you end up with attribute values like `fill=""yellow""` which is not valid. Hence, the black default color.

One way around this might be to get rid of the quotation marks in the CSV itself. If this is not feasible, you might adjust your color accessor function `col` to something like the following:

```
var col = function(d) {return d.COLOR.substring(1, d.COLOR.length - 1)};
```

Have a look at this working demo:

```js
var data = [{ COLOR: '"yellow"'}];

var col = function(d) { return d.COLOR.substring(1, d.COLOR.length - 1); };

d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", col);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```